# PAM Authentication over FTP with Berkley DB

Tags: pam, vsftpd

I was trying to implement PAM authentication over ftp using **Berkeley DB 6.2.32** and did all the configurations required for virtual user, but still I am facing problem while logging in the ftp server through virtual users and when I make changes in `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` file, local users are also denied for the ftp access.

My default `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` file looks like the following:

```
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd_vusers.db onerr=succeed
# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.
# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required        pam_shells.so
```

Please suggest me how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, plugin `pam_listfile` doesn't work with Berkley DB. It works with arbitrary files as wrote in [man 8 pam_listfile](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_listfile).

Secondly, plugin for works with Berkley DB named `pam_userdb`. It's well described in [man 8 pam_userdb](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_userdb). Good example is also present in the mentioned man page:

> auth  sufficient pam_userdb.so icase db=/etc/dbtest.db